# Custom domain name with Heroku and Network Solutions

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I have followed a few guides and SO questions on how to point my domain name to my heroku app. Ultimately I want the domain `www.app.teamengine.co.uk` to point to my heroku app and `www.teamengine.co.uk` to point to my squarespace website.

I have ended up with the following settings on Network Solutions:

Any assistance would be really helpful.

**A Records**

[image]

**CNAME Records**

[image]

[image]

None of the hosts being recognised:

[image]